# Issue with definite integration by parts using IntegrateByParts

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs, symbolic, resourcefunction

**Introduced in 1.0.0 of `ResourceFunction["IntegrateByParts"]`, persisting through 2.0.0.**

---

I am trying to prove Cauchy's identity with Mathematica `ResourceFunction["IntegrateByParts"]`. It doesn't seem to work with definite integration. Cauchy's identity says:
$$
\int_{a}^{x}dz\int_{a}^{z}dy f(y)=\int_{a}^{x} (x-y)f(y)dy
$$
To prove Cauchy's identity I introduce a function `F[z_] -> Inactive[Integrate][f[y], {y, a, z}]`. Then, using IntegrateByParts on `F[z]`, and applying the substitution rule `F'[z] -> f[z]` yields:

```
ResourceFunction["IntegrateByParts"][ F[z], {z, a, x}];
% /. {F[z_] -> Inactive[Integrate][f[y], {y, a, z}]};
% /. F'[z_] -> f[z] // Activate
```

This is not the expected result from Cauchy's identity. How can the IntegrationByParts be modified to work and verify Cauchy's identity?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think it's a bug of `ResourceFunction["IntegrateByParts"]`. The output of

```
ResourceFunction["IntegrateByParts"][F[z], {z, a, x}]
```

is

```
-F[a] + F[x] - Inactive[Integrate][z Derivative[1][F][z], {z, a, x}]
```

but clearly the correct output should be

```
-a F[a] + x F[x] - Inactive[Integrate][z Derivative[1][F][z], {z, a, x}]
```

By checking the source code (it can be found by `` DirectoryName@FindFile@"ResourceFunctionHelpers`" <> "\\IntegrateByPart.wl" // SystemOpen ``, at least on *Windows 10*), there seems to be a mistake in the definition of `makeResult`. The

```
Subtract@@(f /. {{x -> hi}, {x -> lo}})
```

should be modified to

```
Subtract@@(u v /. {{x -> hi}, {x -> lo}})
```

With this correction, your code will give the desired result. BTW the code can be simplified to

```
ResourceFunction["IntegrateByParts"][F[z], {z, a, x}]
% /. F -> Function[z, Inactive[Integrate][f[y], {y, a, z}]]
% // Activate
```

---

It's disappointing to find that, though the function has been updated to 2.0.0 in 2023.3.23 according to the version history, the bug is still there. We still need to fix it ourselves with the method above.

Comment: Thanks! This looks good. But I can't check the source code, I get $Failed when running ```DirectoryName@FindFile@"ResourceFunctionHelpers`" <> "\\IntegrateByPart.wl" // SystemOpen```. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Ferca Which system are you in? Does `$UserBasePacletsDirectory <> 
  "\\Repository\\ResourceFunctionHelpers-1.3.1\\Kernel\\IntegrateByPart.wl" // SystemOpen` work? Can you find a `IntegrateByPart.wl` file under `$UserBasePacletsDirectory`?

Comment: I am running a Mathematica (V 12.1.1.0) notebook in a Mac OS X x86. The filenames I get after running ```$UserBasePacletsDirectory``` are ```{"Configuration", "Repository", "Temporary"}```. The command ```$UserBasePacletsDirectory <> 
  "\\Repository\\ResourceFunctionHelpers-1.3.1\\Kernel\\\
IntegrateByPart.wl" // SystemOpen```also gives me ```$Failed```

Comment: @Ferca I'm on _Windows 10_ so can't test, but can you visit the directory outside of _Mathematica_?

Comment: Yes, ```IntegrateByPart.wl```is in the folder in the directory output from running ```DirectoryName@
  FindFile@"ResourceFunctionHelpers`" <> "\\IntegrateByPart.wl"```. I can find it by using the terminal, but not the point/click window system (no folders show up)

Comment: @Ferca The directory is hidden on Windows, I guess it's similar on Mac OS X.

Comment: Thanks for this. I modified the source part for ```makeResult``` by using an editor from the terminal. The code works and the result of ``ÌntegrationByParts``` produces the expected result!

Comment: Has this bug been reported?

Comment: @SjoerdSmit Yes, I reported it, the Wolfram function repository team replied that "This has been sent to the author of the function".